# Allowing Custom Capability to Manage Plugin Options

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, user-roles, capabilities

## Question

Is it possible to give a custom capability the ability to manage the options of specific plugins?

## Background

I am developing a suite of plugins, a main one with some additional modules. The main one adds a custom role and capability so that this role is an editor plus can manage and edit the rest of the plugins in the suite.

```
// In main plugin, on activation hook
$permissions = get_role( 'editor' );
$permissions = $permissions->capabilities;
$permissions[ 'custom_capability' ] = 1;

add_role( 'custom_role', __( 'Custom Role' ), $permissions );
```

To give access to the plugin pages, I've changed the `capability` when registering the options page of the plugin components to `custom_capability`, which has worked to make the plugins visible to those with the `Custom Role` role.

```
add_submenu_page( 'custom-plugins', 'Custom Plugins Addon', 'Addon', 'custom_capability', 'custom-plugins-addon', 'add_custom_addon_options_page' );
```

However, **when this role tries to update the plugin settings, it is denied access**.

I've tried using the [`option_page_capability`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_page_capability_option_page/) filter, but haven't had any luck.

```
// In additional modules, when registering options page
function give_custom_role_access() {
    return 'custom_capability';
}
apply_filters( 'option_page_capability_custom_addon_options_page', 'give_custom_role_access' );
```

Apparently there is some confusion about what should go in `{$option_page}` when using the `option_page_capability_{$option_page}` filter, so I have tried both the option page slug and the settings group slug, but neither have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), that `$option_page` is the value of a *hidden `<input>` field* generated by `settings_fields()`. For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="option_page" value="{Option group name}">
```

So if you have `settings_fields( 'my-group' )` in your code, then the `$option_page` would be `my-group`. See the (as of writing, 5th) note [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/#notes).

Code sample: (tried and tested working)

```
// Register custom option group.
add_action( 'admin_init', function(){
    register_setting( 'my-group', 'test_option' );
} );

// Allows custom role to save options in the above group (my-group).
add_filter( 'option_page_capability_my-group', function( $capability ){
    return 'custom_capability';
} );

// Render the "Custom Plugins Addon" admin page.
function add_custom_addon_options_page() {
    ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1>Custom Plugins Addon</h1>
            <?php settings_errors(); ?>
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <p>
                    <label>Text field:</label>
                    <input name="test_option" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option( 'test_option' ) ); ?>">
                </p>
                <?php settings_fields( 'my-group' ); ?>
                <?php submit_button(); ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

Full code [here](https://pastebin.com/RMfceh6b), but note that in the example, I intentionally did *not* use `add_settings_section()` and `add_settings_field()`.

### UPDATE

*(Sorry, I actually didn't really notice this part in the question)*

> so I have tried both the option page slug and the settings group slug,
>   but neither have worked

The option page slug is not supposed to work (assuming it is different from the settings group slug); however, the settings group slug (or option group name) should work just as in the example I've given.

So maybe you're missing the `settings_fields( 'my-group' )` in your code?..

Try the [example plugin](https://pastebin.com/RMfceh6b) and see where/what you may have done wrong.. if any.

### UPDATE #2

*(Revised on Mar 18 2019 UTC)*

> Figured it out... I was using `apply_filters()` instead of
>   `add_filter()`

I'm glad you figured it out. And that's a good thing to learn from.. :)

> Could you elaborate on when to use `apply_filters()` vs.
>   `add_filter()`?

*Not a complete elaboration, but I hope these help you.*

1. If you have a function or code which returns something, and you want to allow plugins or custom code to filter/change that something output, you can use [`apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) which registers a filter *hook* and applies/runs *callback* functions hooked to that filter:

   ```
   // This function has a hook for a filter named my_filter.
   function my_function() {
       // Allow plugins or custom code to change the output.
       return apply_filters( 'my_filter', 'default output' );
   }

   // This function does **not** have any hooks.
   function my_function2() {
       return 'something good..';
   }
   ```
2. When the output of a function or code is not what you want/prefer — and that the function/code has a filter *hook*, you can use [`add_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) (which registers a filter *callback*) to customize the output like so: (the function code could be combined, but I separated them so that you know you can hook as many callbacks as you want to a filter)

   ```
   function filter_my_function_output( $output ) {
       return 'custom output';
   }
   add_filter( 'my_filter', 'filter_my_function_output' );

   function filter_my_function_output2( $output ) {
       return is_user_logged_in() ? 'You are logged-in...' : $output;
   }
   add_filter( 'my_filter', 'filter_my_function_output2' );
   ```

   So the final output could be the one returned by `filter_my_function_output()` or `filter_my_function_output2()`. Or vice-versa, depending on the callback priority:

   ```
   // no priority set explicitly; so defaults to 10
   add_filter( 'my_filter', 'filter_my_function_output' ); // priority = 10

   // using custom priority, which is 1; so this runs before the above
   add_filter( 'my_filter', 'filter_my_function_output', 1 ); // priority = 1
   ```

So in summary to the points #1 and #2 above:

- `my_filter` is the name of a filter
- `my_function()` contains a *hook*/place where the filter `my_filter` is being applied
- `filter_my_function_output()` and `filter_my_function_output2()` are *callback functions* which run when the `my_filter` filter is applied

Comment: Figured it out...
I was using [`apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) instead of [`add_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) because on the page for [`option_page_capability`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_page_capability_option_page/) it is shown with `apply_filters()`.

Could you elaborate on when to use `apply_filters()` vs. `add_filters()`?

Comment: I have added an update.. I hope it helps.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome! And btw, I +1 the question because it's quite useful (to me), and once you can, I hope you'd upvote my answer.. :)

Comment: I know! I already tried, to my great disappointment :P

Comment: Well, thanks for trying! You know I appreciate it... :D